# UnitTest to add a new line in a Csv File doesn't work

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I try to do my UnitTest to write a new line in a .csv file but when i call My function data.TestAddToCsv() doesn't add a new line. If i use it in my program instead it works.
This is my program method function :

```
public void AddToCvs(Estate estate)
{
    try
    {
        if (estate is Apartment apartment)
        {

            string line = apartment.address + "," + apartment.cap + "," + apartment.city + "," + apartment.aream2 + "," + apartment.id + "," + apartment.numRoom + "," + apartment.numBath;

            File.AppendAllLines(apartmentFilePath, new string[] { line });
        }
        else if (estate is House house)
        {
            string line = house.address + "," + house.cap + "," + house.city + "," + house.aream2 + "," + house.id + "," + house.numRoom + "," + house.numBath + "," + house.gardenm2;

            File.AppendAllLines(houseFilePath, new string[] { line });
        }
        else if (estate is Box box)
        {
            string line = box.address + "," + box.cap + "," + box.city + "," + box.aream2 + "," + box.id +     "," + box.numParkingSpace;

            File.AppendAllLines(boxFilePath, new string[] { line });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

this is my [TestMethod]

```
public void TestAddToCsv()
{
    string address = "Via Catania";
    string cap = "54896";
    string city = "Milano";
    int aream2 = 200;
    string id = "A8";
    int numRoom = 8;
    int numBath = 2;
    string mainApartmentPath = @"C:/Users/FMF-guest/.../bin/Debug/net6.0/ApartmentCsv.csv";
    string testApartmentPath = @"C:/Users/FMF-guest/.../AgenziaImmobiliareTest/ApartmentCsv.csv";

    var lineTest = "Via Catania,54896,Milano,200,A8,8,2";
    Apartment newApartment = new Apartment(address, cap, city, aream2, id, numRoom, numBath);
    
    DataFiles data = new DataFiles();
                          
    data.TestAddToCsv(newApartment);            
    
    File.AppendAllLines(testApartmentPath, new string[] { lineTest });
   
    var result = File.ReadAllText(mainApartmentPath);
    var expectedResult = File.ReadAllText(testApartmentPath);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);

}
```

Try to change the public/private state of my function or create a new equal function using public variables for my programm but still doesn't work

Comment: Where is the `TestAddToCsv(Estate estate)` method?

Comment: Your `AddToCsv(…)` method can not be tested by a **unit** test. You should abstract the dependency of the File methods to mock them for a **unit** test

Comment: TestAddToCsv() item is in a project unit test, binding with my main project in addition now i try to change my path in my main project from an absolute path string mainApartmentPath = @"C:/... in a relative path 
private static string apartmentFilePath = @"C:/Users/FMF-guest/source/repos/Luigi.Distefano/AgenziaImmobiliare/AgenziaImmobiliare/bin/Debug/net6.0/ApartmentCsv.csv";

So the algorithm works but maybe the test didn't see the absolute path correctly ?

Comment: How can i abstract the dependency  of the File methods?

Comment: Where is the code of the method you called by `data.TestAddToCsv(newApartment)`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems like there's a typo in your test's acting code, you're calling the test method itself:

```
data.TestAddToCsv(newApartment);
```

instead of the method declared in the first snippet box (which also contains a typo):

```
 data.AddToCvs(newApartment);
```

You may consider a bit of refactoring of your code first:
(I assumed your class hierarchy from the code you posted)

```
public abstract class Estate
{
    protected string Address { get; set; }
    protected string Cap { get; set; }
    protected string City { get; set; }
    protected int AreaM2 { get; set; }
    protected string Id { get; set; }

    protected Estate(string address, string cap, string city, int areaM2, string id)
    {
        Address = address;
        Cap = cap;
        City = city;
        AreaM2 = areaM2;
        Id = id;
    }

    public new virtual string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Address},{Cap},{City},{AreaM2},{Id}";
    }
}

public abstract class EstateForPeople : Estate
{
    protected int NumRoom { get; set; }
    protected int NumBath { get; set; }

    protected EstateForPeople(string address, string cap, string city, int areaM2, string id, int numRoom, int numBath)
        : base(address, cap, city, areaM2, id)
    {
        NumRoom = numRoom;
        NumBath = numBath;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{base.ToString()},{NumRoom},{NumBath}";
    }
}

public class Apartment : EstateForPeople
{
    public Apartment(string address, string cap, string city, int areaM2, string id, int numRoom, int numBath)
        : base(address, cap, city, areaM2, id, numRoom, numBath)
    {
    }
}

public class House : EstateForPeople
{
    public int GardenM2 { get; set; }

    public House(string address, string cap, string city, int areaM2, string id, int numRoom, int numBath, int gardenM2)
        : base(address, cap, city, areaM2, id, numRoom, numBath)
    {
        GardenM2 = gardenM2;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{base.ToString()},{GardenM2}";
    }
}

public class Box : Estate
{
    public int NumParkingSpace { get; set; }

    public Box(string address, string cap, string city, int areaM2, string id, int numParkingSpace)
        : base(address, cap, city, areaM2, id)
    {
        NumParkingSpace = numParkingSpace;
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{base.ToString()},{NumParkingSpace}";
    }
}
```

At this point you don't need to build the string equivalent of an Estate, you can easily use .ToString's overrides to turn classes into their string representation.

The write responsible class may become something like this:

```
public class DataFiles
{
    public string GetPathFor<T>(T estate) where T : Estate
    {
        return estate switch
        {
            Apartment => "apartment path",
            House => "house path",
            Box => "box path",
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
        };
    }

    public void AddToCsv<T>(T estate, string path) where T : Estate
    {
        File.AppendAllLines(path, new[] { estate.ToString() });
    }
}
```

Then you can refactor your test:

```
   public void TestAddToCsv()
    {
        //Arrange
        var testApartmentPath = @"C:/Users/FMF-guest/.../AgenziaImmobiliareTest/ApartmentCsv.csv";
        Apartment newApartment = new Apartment("Via Catania", "54896", "Milano", 200, "A8", 8, 2);
        DataFiles data = new DataFiles();
        var expectedLine = newApartment.ToString();

        //Act
        data.AddToCsv(newApartment, testApartmentPath);
        var wroteLine = File.ReadAllText(testApartmentPath);
        
        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedLine, wroteLine);
    }
```

And in your production code:

```
{
        /*
         * ...
         * code here
         * ...
         */
        var apartmentPath = data.GetPathFor(apartment);
        data.AddToCsv(apartment, apartmentPath);
        /*
         * ...
         * eventual code here
         * ...
         */
    }
```

You have now a much clearer separation of responsibilities among you're classes and methods and testing and maintaining will be easier as well.

The key point here, to clearly answer your question, is to be aware of what you are testing. I'm not completely sure about what was wrong in first place with your test due to the typos I earlier reported but even without typo you were making things hard in that test.
If I got it correctly you were double writing the string representation of an apartment, once through the unit under test (AddToCsv()) and once directly calling File.AppendAllLines, but in two different files. Than reading both files and try to assert that both strings were equally write.
As you write test for your code try follow a much linear flow:

1. Clearly state what's your unit under test
2. Have clear what's the purpose of the unit under test (a tons of times, this is not easy due to lose decoupling and no SRP applied)
3. Have clear which is the condition you're testing (best case, worst case, corner cases, throw exception case, etc...)
4. Write test (and code) as simple as possible
5. Do trustworthy assertion

In your specific case the answer to these question should have been:

1. AddToCsv()
2. This method should write a string into a file
3. Given a path (**whatever path**) the unit under test writes a given string
4. Provide a test path, the string that have to be written, call the unit under test
5. Assert that the unit under test did what you were testing. In this case it wrote something (and eventually, if the writing outcome is as expected. This is arguable, you can also write two different test for these two different aspect of the assertion, but in my opinion for such small unit under test it's ok to put them together).

Learning how to properly unit test things is a hard and not always clear path but in the end (and I'm still far from the end as well!) it pays. A lot.